# Photovoltaic cell - why is I-V curve so strange

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, electrons, semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

Today I was doing practicals with PV cells and my team was measuring IV curve of a solar cell. The cell was not homogenously illuminated and the illumination was very strong.

Our measurements were carried out by changing the load in the circuit (look picture below)

[image]

The obtained I-V curve was looking like that:

[image]

What may be the cause? This doesn't even remotely remind of a photovoltaic cell (IV characteristic for proper PV cell is presented below as a red curve)

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect the I-V output curve of a solar cell under illumination to look like the I-V curve of a diode?

Comment: @JonCuster Because for a normal cell it should still be a diagram like one for a diode, but shifted with respect to axes. At least that's what my teacher said.

Comment: Try considering that in a diode you would usually consider a current "I" of opposite sign.

Comment: @DavideM but this way of drawing I-V curves is a convention for PV cells.

Comment: Draw your curve by considering an opposite sign for "I", then you'll see the diode's I-V characteristic shifted due to illumination.

Comment: This is just matter of contacts polarity/convention. Congratulation to the teacher

Comment: @Alchimista but can you tell me why is the shape so strange?

Comment: There is nothing strange on it. May be not a very nice efficient cell but it is what you should get

Comment: As compared to a diode the shift should be seen for current as well for voltage. Else a solar cells would not be a source of energy

Comment: @Alchimista I know how a correct I-V curve should look like, but I want to know why is this characteristic so different from one for a normal cell.

Comment: What you show is a solar cells! What do you mean for a normal one? Put the figure of what you consider normal then.... Because else I do not see your point

Comment: Ok. Now what you put is not a good example of a solar cell but an example of a good solar cell, if you see the difference :). Basically in your case the FF of the cell is low. But this might be real or simply due to the fact that the cell was not homogeneously illuminated. Think of half in dark and half illuminated: your final curve will be the sum of the two components, and this will obviously result in a rounder curve

Comment: Besides the fact that a cell should be homogeneously illuminated, it might be that it gets old. FF depends on numerous factors, usually people list them as serial resistance, shunt resistance. I do not like because it tells almost nothing on the "how" , especially experimenting with new materials. I assume your device was something out of a pocket calculator or out of a kit. So it can be old and starting to have high resistance at the electrodes, poor transport, and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's make clear that an I-V curve of an illuminated solar cell should not look like the I-V curve of a diode in dark.

Also the way of plotting and the sign of the current are matter of convention and use, and this can differ for different communities as well as on a geographical base.

The curve you plotted is more than reasonable for a solar cell. It just shows a cell whose efficiency (independent of the short circuit current and open circuit voltage) is limited by a low filling factor, the ratio of the maximum power of the solar cell and the product  Isc x Voc. Graphically you see this as a curvature, opposite to the "rectangleness" of an ideal case.

The actual photovoltaic trace of your device can be seen as the sum of IV curve in dark and that of "light only" curve. As such, at least in well established solar cells materials and devices, a nice diode behaviour in dark is a prerequisite for a nice efficient solar cell.

If the cell in dark already show a ohmic component, this will be present under illumination too, reducing the photocurrent every where in the quadrant of interest (except at V = 0).

Conversely, if the diodes does not rectify in the sense that does not open at all, this can point to high resistance, either due to negligible charge injection or recombination of charges and/ or poor contact at whatever point a contact is required (electrodes, interfaces).

The causes of the above can obviously resides at the material level as well as the constructive one. So it is hard to tell what could be the parameter which mostly affect the filling factor of your cell without knowing the type and its IV characteristics in dark.

This would apply if you would have (properly) illuminated the cell *homogeneously*, which is not the case. Actually we have now a I-V curve which results from numerous components : the dark curve, and the hypothetical light only ones. Note that the latters will contributes with unknown weights.

If you consider that current, voltage as well FF depends on illumination intensity, it should be clear that a not homogeneously illuminated solar cell is prone to show a less squared (rectangular) trace in the quadrant of concern.

In your case I guess that the result is due to both the non homogeneous illumination as well as an ageing device used for the practical exercise. If it's of interest, you could measure the same under a more homogeneous illumination without forgetting to run a dark measurement.